# Changing the color of tab titles in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

[image: Text into tabs Sublime Text]

The color scheme I am using has poor visibility of tab titles. How do I change their color? I want to change it both for active and inactive tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your `Default.sublime-theme`, where `tab_label` sets the color of the text and `tab_control` the color of the tab itself:

```js
[
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "fg": [127, 255, 212]
    },
    {
        "class": "tab_control",
        "attributes": ["selected"],
        "tint_modifier": [255, 215, 0, 225]
    }
]
```

in the attribute `fg` you define a rgb based color. If you want it only for the selected tab you can add `"parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected"]}],` to limit its scope.

Comment: Sorry, and whether I can change at the same time colors at tabs and at the text in tabs? I want that color of my active tab remained same as on [the picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4RbAD.jpg). But it turns out that color either only at tabs or only at the text in tabs changes. [My `Default.sublime-theme` file](http://dim.st/t6041.txt). Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных I modified my answer to clearify how to join the `tab_label` and `tab_control` classes.

Answer (score 0):

If **Material Theme Package** installed, add following settings at "Preferences" >> "Customize Theme"

In "rules" lable add following settings.

```
"rules":
[
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "fg": [255, 255, 255]
    }
]
```